# App script returns array_literal error in master sheet project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I´m working on a Master sheet project, using the guidelines that appear in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/SyB4MVkWV3c

Basically, this script filters column "E" in every sheet (tab) that appears in my document and every time it hits with the word "Pendiente", lists some values on the "Master" tab. The goal is to list all the pending orders in my master sheet, and whenever the order is fullfilled, erase the "Pendiente" (pending) cell from any of the tabs so that it doesen´t show on my master tab.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ignoreSheets =  ["Master"];
  
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  const filteredListOfSheets = allSheets.filter(s => ignoreSheets.indexOf(s.getSheetName()) == -1 )
  
  let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `filter({'${s.getSheetName()}'!B2:E, "${s.getSheetName()} / Fila "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!C2:C)},(ISNUMBER('${s.getSheetName()}'!C2:C)),'${s.getSheetName()}'!E2:E="Pendiente")`)
  
  let formulaText = "={" + formulaArray.join(";") + "}";
  //console.log(formulaText);
  ss.getSheetByName("Master").getRange("A2").setFormula(formulaText);
```

This works fine until a certain point where I go back for example and erase the word "pendiente" from any tab (different from master tab). From there, the formula start showing this error:

> "in array_literal, an array literal was missing values for one or more rows"

I´m aware that this kind of error appears when there are merged cells for example but that´s not my case.  Also, I´ve checked and all the tabs have the same number of columns. The resulting formula shows this:

> ={filter({'Ventas 17-9'!B2:E, "Ventas 17-9 / Fila "&ROW('Ventas 17-9'!C2:C)},(ISNUMBER('Ventas 17-9'!C2:C)),'Ventas 17-9'!E2:E="Pendiente");...

The strange thing is that until I start deleting this "Pendiente" cells, the script works just fine. Perhaps it has something to do with my sharing configuration? This script has been written from a Gsuite account and the spreadsheet is shared with non Gsuite users.

Screenshots:
Master Tab[image]
Example tab, where the infromation is pulled from[image]}

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `{'Ventas 17-9'!B2:E, "Ventas 17-9 / Fila "&ROW('Ventas 17-9'!C2:C)}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the formula `filter` is not finding the matching situation in one of your sheets (if your sheet does not contain `Pendiente` you will encounter this error) and therefore it is returning a single `N/A` occupying a single cell value.

This is a malformed array because on the sheets where `filter` matches the search you are printing 5 columns (the data you are pulling) while on the ones that it does not find `Pendiente` it is trying to return just a single `N/A` value.

To solve this, you can wrap your `filter` formulas in an `iferror` that will change the value `N/A` by 5 values that will match the rest of sheets that do actually match the filter. The important thing is that all your rows have the same number of columns to avoid this error.

So, to solve it, change the line of your script by this (of course instead of 0 you can print whatever you want but it must be printed in all 5 columns):

```js
let formulaArray = filteredListOfSheets.map(s => `iferror(filter({'${s.getSheetName()}'!B2:E, "${s.getSheetName()} / Fila "&ROW('${s.getSheetName()}'!C2:C)},(ISNUMBER('${s.getSheetName()}'!C2:C)),'${s.getSheetName()}'!E2:E="Pendiente"),{"","","","",""})`)
```

Reference:

[IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

Comment: Thank´s Mateo for such a valuable feedback! Your solution solves the previous error very smoothly. However, Now i´m getting a (0,0,0,0,0) row for every tab that i´m adding in my sheet. This could be fixed by a adding a filter to one of my columns so that it doesn´t show this 0,0,0,0,0 rows. The only problem is every time I have a new "Pendiente" order, I need to go back to the master tab and edit this column filter because otherwise, it doesn´t show the new updates.  Perhaps there is a way to solve this via code?

Comment: Hi ! A row of 0s is being added because these new tabs do not have any Pendiente order and therefore, the filter would return NA (in our case this NA is being substituted by 0s). Dont you want these 0s to come out when a sheet does not contain Pendiente ? I have edited my question to not write anything when Pendiente is not found on the sheet (you just need to substitute 0s by ```""```. What do you mean by *every time I have a new "Pendiente" order, I need to go back to the master tab and edit this column filter because otherwise, it doesn´t show the new updates.*? Thanks :D

Comment: Hi Mateo! Because this is a Master Sheet where I´m going to see in a "master tab" all my pending orders, i don´t really need a row of zeros for every tab that doesn´t contain "Pendiente". My goal is to have just the pending orders in this tab and right now this is how it looks: https://i.postimg.cc/4yfG6qmT/Captura.png
 
What I meant by "editing the column filter" is that if I will work with all of these rows of zeros and I don´t want to see them, I would need to use a filter in the column that only brings the cells with something different than 0 and that process is kind of manual.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. I have fix the 0s issue.